# How can I change the number of decimals in a table?

Tags: tables, formatting, automation

I have a massive table where each element has 10 decimals. Is it possible to convert the entire table to smaller like 2 or 4 decimals long? I searched and found that I might need to use the `siunitx` package. But I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Can you please add a sample table wrapped inside a compilable document?